# Splitting a list into N parts to get a list of tuples

Tags: python

I've a list in which I have to split it in 9 parts but I got a list of lists, and I want to get a list of tuples. I don´t know if I can do this on python.

```
data= [1, 'PURECO', 'WOMAN', 'MARISCAL', 'MULLER', 28, 'DIABETES', 'APC', 2020-01-03, 2, 'CAO', 'WOMAN', 'CAL Y MAYOR', 'URTIZ', 34, 'OBESIDAD TIPO 1', 'APC', 2020-01-03]
```

I tried this:

```
data = [data[i:i+9] for i in range(0, len(data),9)]
```

I got this:

```
data= [[1, 'PURECO', 'WOMAN', 'MARISCAL', 'MULLER', 28, 'DIABETES', 'APC', 2020-01-03],[ 2, 'CAO', 'WOMAN', 'CAL Y MAYOR', 'URTIZ', 34, 'OBESIDAD TIPO 1', 'APC', 2020-01-03]]
```

But, I want to get this:

```
data= [(1, 'PURECO', 'WOMAN', 'MARISCAL', 'MULLER', 28, 'DIABETES', 'APC', 2020-01-03),(2, 'CAO', 'WOMAN', 'CAL Y MAYOR', 'URTIZ', 34, 'OBESIDAD TIPO 1', 'APC', 2020-01-03)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is almost finished, you can just convert to `tuple`:

```
data = [tuple(data[i:i+9]) for i in range(0, len(data),9)]
        ^                ^
        this will convert inner lists to tuples
```

> ```
> >>> [tuple(data[i:i+9]) for i in range(0, len(data),9)]
> [(1, 'PURECO', 'WOMAN', 'MARISCAL', 'MULLER', 28, 'DIABETES', 'APC', '2020-01-03'), (2, 'CAO', 'WOMAN', 'CAL Y MAYOR', 'URTIZ', 34, 'OBESIDAD TIPO 1', 'APC', '2020-01-03')]
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
list_of_tuples = [tuple(item) for item in data]
```